# Why is my validation code for .net core 3. not working as intended?

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, asp.net-core

I am trying to make a validation for my report form where the report can only be submited if the email = to "Sample@email.com". My problem is the code works perfectly without the validation but when I include the validation code `if (!ModelState.IsValid){return View("Create");}` into the my controller the validation works perfectly but when the email is correct it just refreshes the page without submiting it or redirecting it to the submit view

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Submit(Reports report)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Create");
            }

        _reportRepository.CreateReport(report);
        return View();
```

Validation Code:

```
public class EmailValidation : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var report = (Reports)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            if (report.Email == "Sample@email.com")
                {

                    return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid email");
        }
    }
```

Report:

```
public class Reports
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReportId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter email.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email :")]
        [EmailValidation(ErrorMessage ="enter valid email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Create View:

```
@model Reports
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
<body>

    <form asp-action="Submit" method="post" role="form">
        <div class="container1">
         <div class=" form-group row">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group row float-right">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5 float-md-left">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the `Reports` model, assume it is decorated with `[Email]` Also you have a `EmailVAlidation` not `EmailValidation` which might be a typo here or in your code

Comment: I added the model and view. And the VAlidation typo was brought through to the model.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the ModelState.IsValid is always false even though the ValidationResult.Success; should set it as true

Comment: wonder if its a conflict of `namespaces` rename class to `ReportEmailValidation` and try again

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.So you means although get into `return ValidationResult.Success`.It always gets into `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` statement?Could you set the breakpoint to check the error message in ModelState?